# How can I show the active state of a child by clicking it's parent?

Tags: html, css

How can I show the active state of a child when it's parent is clicked? In the example code below, I want to click on the div and have the `<a>` tag's active state show as well. Help?

```css
div:active {
  background-color: pink;
}

a:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">w3schools.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Two elements can't really be "active" at the same time but if you want to style the link based on when the div is active your selector can be `div:active > a`

Comment: Do you want a click on the div, off the link text, to trigger the link as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the descendent selector `>` (or any other selector which will target the child of an `:active` parent) to style the child when the parent is `active`.

```css
div:active {
  background-color: pink;
}

div:active > a, a:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">w3schools.com</a>
</div>
```